# Finding the equation of the circle passing through two points $(4,4)$ and $(-2,-2)$ with radius $4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

After solving using Sim Eq, obtained are $h=1$ and $k=1$, but I could not prove it as I did not get the exact radius $4$. My radius would always slightly run such as $18$ or $15$. Is there a step I miscalculated or skipped?

Comment: Instead of making everyone guess where you made a mistake, show your work.

Comment: If you show your work here we can help you in a more effective way.

Comment: @Sya Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Let consider the general equation $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=16$$ and use the conditions

- $(4-a)^2+(4-b)^2=16$
- $(-2-a)^2+(-2-b)^2=16$

to find the center coordinates $(a,b)$.

Comment: can this be solved using the matrix method for solving system of equation?

Comment: No it can’t since we obtai a quadratic equation with 2 different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the distance between the two points is $6\sqrt2\gt8$, there is no such circle.